# Why is the file icon usually folded from the right corner?

Tags: icons, files

I'm doing a bit of iconography which got me thinking about the standard icon for a document / file shown below:

[image: File Icon Examples]

Why do the majority of these icons have the folder corner on the right hand side? Why is it seldom seen on the left and would it be detrimental to put it on the left? Is there a logical design reason for this? Or is it just a case of the first one sets the trend?

My question expands on the question here:
[What does an folded corner (earmarked page) represent to a user?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111217/what-does-an-folded-corner-earmarked-page-represent-to-a-user)

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote?

Comment: Honestly I believe it's to show that it's a document (sheet of paper). Without it it would be a simple blank rectangle. I don't think it has any specific meaning outside of that. I don't think anyone would fold the top right corner of the page, especially in countries that read left-to-right.

Comment: @NibblyPig So you think it would have little to no effect if the fold would be on the left side instead?

Comment: That's correct. I think someone just wanted a blank piece of paper icon but thought a rectangle wouldn't convey it was a sheet of paper, so they just folded the edge over, arbitrarily picking a corner.

Comment: @NibblyPig I doubt it was arbitrary. The majority of people are right-handed. If you're holding a stack of sheets of paper, or you're flipping through a file containing multiple sheets, you're likely to hold with your left and fold with your right; the top-right corner is therefore the easiest place to do that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the question was to be interpreted as "why are file icons folded" or "why are file icons folded specifically from the right side". But when flipping through paper or turning the pages of a book I would never touch the top right corner, and I would never fold it into a triangle. If you were representing that action you'd do bottom right, like reading a book. To turn the pages of a book from the top right takes more effort and you have to rotate your hand. With a stapled stack of papers you wouldn't be able to use the top right, you'd flip from the bottom up and over.

Comment: I also think as a right handed person it's easier to flip with your left-hand a stapled stack of sheets, if the staple is top left, since you're not reaching over so far. I would certainly use my left hand, from the bottom edge, to flip it over the top.

Comment: @NibblyPig However, before I learnt never to fold the corner of a page of a book to mark my place, I (and everyone I've seen do the same) always folds the top-right corner down.

Comment: Users aren't required to state why they downvote. Although the description of the downvote button is often relevant: *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*. Personally speaking I'd say this question falls into the latter part 'not useful'. There is no use you can do with the knowledge acquired by this question, and it's not really solving any real-world problem that you're currently trying to address. It's just a '*hmm, this is weird*' bikeshed question.

Comment: I don't this it is intended as a bookmark. They used to fold a few pages like this to keep them together as a document. See my answer below.

Comment: Certainly it would not be in the middle of the page.

Comment: @JonW to be honest I don't know why this question attracted a lot of debate either. I asked it because in my team's project we were debating between different icons for a particular case and one argued for left-sided fold document. I know people aren't required to but surely critical feedback can help improve the question? (in most cases)

Comment: As I say, it's a Bikeshed question really. Something that doesn't require expert specific knowledge on to answer, many people will have an opinion and it's a simple distraction from more complicated problems. Jeff Atwood has a good piece about such questions: https://blog.codinghorror.com/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect/ No offence to your question, all Stack Exchange sites get similar relatively simple questions periodically that get really popular.

Comment: @JonW I think the "Hot Network Questions" can be renamed to "The Bikeshed" without meta discussion and nobody would disagree

Comment: @JonW None taken, but I still think these kinds of question threads have value for the community. There is a lot of knowledge in the comments & answers on this one which, although is related to this bikeshed talk, is still quite insightful.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The original, by [Norm Cox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_Cox_(designer)), had the [dog ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_ears) in the bottom left. This was made for [Xerox Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerox_Star) system, <strike>and it was a bit of an odd choice since typically, in a book, the dog ear is in the top right corner</strike>*. ([source](http://www.digibarn.com/collections/software/xerox-star/xerox-world-according-to-norm.html))

[image]

It was only a latter concept that changed the position of the dog ear to its current position:

[image]

<sub>* This sentence was not based in any factual evidence. Some users pointed out that it might be an incorrect assumption. Thus the [Strikethrough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough).</sub>

---

In [The Xerox Star: a retrospective paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.911.6741&rep=rep1&type=pdf) ([Johson, et al., 1989](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/35211/authors#authors)) you'll find the reason for moving the bottom-left corner dog ear to the top right and I quote:

> Figure 6. Match the medium. Many graphic refinements were made during
>   the design process. For example, the turned corner of the document
>   icon was moved to the top so that the three lines of label would line
>   up with the labels of other icons.

For convenience here is the figure retrieved from the paper (pdf is freely available):

[image: top right corner paper icon]

This made sense at the time. Today I would assume it's done because that is what is familiar to the user. In my experience (and I've made quite a few paper icons derivatives) I use the top-right corner because it feels familiar and intuitive.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer I meant to answer your question but for some reason got confused and ended up answering your linked question (which already had an accepted answer). That is the reason for the duplication of information. It's still valid for both though.

Comment: I've done a similar thing before. It's an easy mistake to make when links don't open new tabs here.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Links shouldn't open in new tabs _anywhere_ unless the *user* wants them to, and therefore uses their middle mouse button (or CTRL key) to click them. The target attribute of A elements was deprecated for a while because of the anti-user-friendly behaviour it enabled.

Comment: @AaronF It was deprecated in XHTML1.1, but brought back in HTML5. I used to agree with your position that only the user should be able to open links in new windows/tabs, but now I see that in some cases it is a smart default, like on Reddit. It depends on your use-case and make sure you do usability research first!

Comment: In a book, the dog ear would be top left or top right, depending on whether you're marking the left or right page from the binding.

Comment: While a book gets dog eared on the top right corner (assuming a book ordered left-to-right as virtually all English books are), a notepad tends to get dog eared on the bottom left corner.

Comment: It was not a dog ear initially. Look at this picture which claims to show the evolution of the icon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Evolution_of_the_document_icon_shape.jpg
We can see that they started with the empty paper, then tried various ways to make it more obviously a paper. Iteration 5 looks more like when you are going to lift the paper from a table. This was probably turned into a dog ear to fit with the sharp angles of the design language.

Comment: @EmilVikström I believe those were sketches prior to release. Specifically I'm recognizing (1) and (4) as being Wallace Judd and David Smith respectively You can see it yourself in the "source" link in the answer that Smith (1) is chronologically more recent than Judd (4). For this answer I've only added the Cox concept (early and final) which was the one eventually used. But the "source" link has more information.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps it's a personal quirk but I've always added the dog ear to the top right (even if the bookmarked page is the left one). This is evidently a "ruleless" habit with no right or wrong answer but if I were in Cox position I would likely have opted for the top-right corner dog ear also. But it would be, indeed, an intuitive choice, not fact based.

Comment: @Dai my main problem with defaulting to open in a new tab/window is that there's no way for the user to decide that they want the link to open in the current window if they want to. It's a pain on desktop, but easy enough to middle-click (or Ctrl+Shift+Tab, Ctrl+w) the previous tab to close it, but it's very annoying on mobile where it's hard to notice it happened. I have a 'back' button and know how to use it, there's no need for a site to break usability like this; it's clingy, desperate behaviour, like popup windows and onClose scripts, and needs to stop (eg: a "same-domain" new tab policy)

Comment: @Barmar Many books have chapters starting on right-hand pages, which means that the preceding left-hand page will be only partially full of text, or even blank. So a dog-ear is _slightly_ more likely on a right-hand page. But, aside from the silly quibble, I agree that it's wrong for the answer to assert that dog-ears are "typically" on the right.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My logic was that most people are right-handed. Myself included and I constantly use the top-right corner folds (even if the important stuff is on the left page). But it's true that I don't really know if the right side is more common. As I mentioned previously to Barmar it was an intuitive leap, not based on facts. In any case given the level of interest in this point I'll remove that sentence (Strikethrough) as it is indeed speculative.

Comment: I turnover only the top right corners.  But since I've seen Apple doing it since 1986, it's possible that I got the idea off them.

Comment: @armatita I dog-ear the page that I stopped reading on, so I know where to resume. So it's either the left or right page, depending on where I stopped.

Comment: @AaronF I can't seem to find any official documentation on _why_ the target attribute was deprecated, but I believe it was because it was mostly used for frames at the time, and this was back when frames were being phased out.

Comment: Top right or bottom left, I guess I could get used to any of these variants.

Comment: Could you add something about consistency as well? If you notice in the first graphic, the "file" icon is bottom left, but the document in the "markup" is in the top right. Since they were directly related, a consistency would be necessary.

Comment: @armatita I really like this answer because it illustrates the history of the icon. But it doesn't provide a logical explanation as to why those choices were made unlike answers provided by Zasul, Martyn and moot. If you could add a bit on that I would accept the answer.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer I did not add an explanation for that because I would have been forced to speculate (a lot). I searched a bit more and it turns out that the reason has nothing to do with how people bookmark a book or the eye trajectory for icon reading. It was made so that consistency existed with other icons. See the attached figure and explanation in the edit (the paper is also linked).

Comment: @armatita Fantastic find!

Answer (score 26):

This is an assumption but many people use to curl a page in a book to set it as a bookmark. 
As the left area is stitched you are left with the top right corner and bottom right corner and it is more natural to curl the top right corner.

As for other types of papers that are not books this might also be the case as the files might be added in a folder or stapled together usually on the left area.

Comment: What about dog ears on the left page of a book? When I was young and still used paper books I am fairly certain I bookmarked the left page just as much as I bookmarked right page... it's all about where you finished reading. If you finish on the left page you mark that one, if you finish on the right one you mark that one.

Comment: And even if you're for some reason talking about closed books (in which case you couldn't see the dog ear in the way it's typically represented) it's still the case that the dog ear will be pointing in either direction equally much (if it's on the left page you would have to look from the back side to "x-ray vision" see the dog ear overlapping with the page.

Comment: Interesting points @DavidMulder, which kind of breaks this answer's logic.

Comment: I did mention that this was an assumption, but can you remember from when you were young when you were opening the book again to your left dog ear if you would open the book there and the dog ear would be on the right side and you would turn that page on the left side and resume your reading ( that is because as you are looking on the side of the book to resume your reading you will grab the pages up untill the dog ear as you cannot grab that one. )

Comment: You pretty much explained to yourself what`s with the left page dog ear by stating: "if it's on the left page you would have to look from the back side to "x-ray vision" see the dog ear overlapping with the page. " because usually you open the book from the top part not from the back side of it. resulting in an always to the right dog ear, even though the curl would be reversed ( which would make no sense to make an icon with a curl reversed)

Answer (score 9):

**History**
This goes back to a time before screens and icons. The fold was used to hold pages together before paperclips were invented. At least I read this somewhere but unfortunately can't find the source. Seemed plausible to me anyway.

**Top right**
Writing left to right you would cover the first thing on the page if the ear was in the top left. The bottom often has page numbers in one of the corners. Top right seems like the best option.

**Skeumorphism**
We've always copied physical forms of thing to explain concepts in digital interfaces. The document with folded corner is no exception. And similar to the save icon, the link to its physical counterpart is getting lost as it's used less and less.

Comment: Don't they put the staples or paper clips on the left hand side of the page so you can flip it easier?

Comment: You could add a picture for your second point. If there is text inside the Page, it can start close to the left edge if the fold is on the right side. Plus the first row is shorter in most cases, while the bottom right of a letter will often include a foot-note.

Answer (score 9):

I think the skeuomorphic position of the "paper fold" is not the issue. The difference between the four positions is too minor. The skeuomorphic meaning of the different fold positions is so close that simple visual effectiveness is what makes the decision.

**I think the position is simply the most effective position for eye scanning.** It's the easiest position to notice when scanning or not looking at it. It's simply more noticeable than the other positions.

[image]

Comment: For people used to western left-to-right writing systems anyway.

Comment: Usually the image/icon is not big enough for scanning to really matter.

Answer (score 8):

If you are reading a book and go to turn the page to the next one, which corner do you normally grab?

In Western, left-to-right-reading countries (and, for better or worse, a lot of things in tech are Western-centric), it's going to be along the right side of the page.  Personally I'm much more likely to grab the top corner because it's easier for my index finger to lift up the top-right corner than it is for my thumb to lift up the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Not every document has to be in a book. It could just be a one page document.

Comment: @RobbyReindeer True, but that doesn't mean that this rationale doesn't apply.  Books set a precedent.  Possibly because of muscle memory from reading books, I tend to flip over one-page documents from the top-right corner.

Answer (score 7):

A picture speaks a thousand words...

[image]

There was a life before computers. In fact, many people actually still use paper and paper files such as the one above. I have one on my desk right now...

Comment: But not all pieces of paper are folded on the top-right corner. I think you missed the point!

Comment: @RobbyReindeer Why must an answer to our question be applicable to *all* pieces of paper?  Not *all* icons have a folded notch in the upper-right corner either.

Answer (score 6):

I see some similar answers to mine but have a bit different perspective.

While making the symbols, to make it easy to understand the makers want it to be easily understandable. So if you see a file in real life it is bound the left side and dog ears on the right side. That's the reason why they always folded on the top right.

I can't answer the other part of your question about folders but maybe it could have a somewhat similar reason.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a typical letter or page of a book:

```
Heading 1

Dear Mr. Lorem Ipsum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et 
accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd 
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur 
sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Signature: ___________________

Footnotes
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est.....
```

A Folding on the left side would collide with the text. Some text would be hidden in the top or lower left, or the whole text would have an unnatural margin on the left.

The bottom right is filled with footnotes or an impressum/signature in many cases and may be "below the fold" e.g. too far down to be visually prominent.

This leaves the top right corner, usually void of text due to headers on the left. It seems just a sensible choice.

Answer (score 4):

This is a guess/opinion, but I think it probably has to do with the majority of people being right handed, and therefore a folded corner makes more sense to be on the right hand side since it will probably have been made by someone's right hand.

Another idea could be that the initial icons were designed by people in countries that read from left to right (e.g. the typical F scan pattern), so that the more important information tends to start on the left hand side. This means that a folded corner on the right hand side is less likely to cover important information.

Comment: The folded corner will be on whatever page it's marking. If it's marking a left-hand page, it'll be on the left, regardless of whether the folder is left- or right-handed.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can only base it on my own behaviour (at least when I used to mark book pages in this way), but I only tend to fold it on the same side of the book because of the reason I mentioned in my answer. But I prefer to use bookmarks for this.

Comment: Definitely with you on bookmarks!

Answer (score 4):

**Why a triangle/notch?**

A blank sheet of paper holds no content. It's orientation does not matter.

A not-blank sheet of paper does hold content. And you do need to worry about its orientation to consume that content.

Its tricky to correctly orient a square or rectangle by shape alone. But, add in a cut-out triangle, and it becomes easier. Think about the notch on SIM cards. Or the notch on "ye olde" floppy disks.

So, I think the notch conveys "there is content here ; and therefore its orientation matters".

**Why on the right?**

Also, I suppose, why on the top? I read top-to-bottom and left-to-right. So, logically, I guess I'd like the 'content/orientation' marker to be at my starting point (top-left). But, darn it, it just feels good and proper for the notch to be on the top-right. So, perhaps, its just cultural convention too?

Comment: The triangle also conveys that it's conveying a piece of paper and not the abstract notion of a rectangle and not a brick or who knows what.

Answer (score -5):

I believe it could be because not all languages read left to right.

Here are a few languages that read right to left: Arabic, Aramaic, Azeri, Dhivehi/Maldivian, Hebrew, Kurdish (Sorani),Persian/Farsi,Urdu, etc.

Chinese, Japanese, and Korean can be read left to right, right to left, top to bottom.

Comment: How does this explain the direction of the icon? If anything, this suggests that the icon should depend on the locale and its writing direction.

Comment: If you read right to left you wouldn't grab the right corner (top or bottom) of a book page you would grab the left corner (top or bottom).  I write my applications in English. If I change the language for use in Japan I wouldn't change any icons.  I wouldn't think a Japanese developer would take the time to (or even think of) changing subtle things like that ether.